# Read file with name, readed from variable, from the res folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a method which receives two variables as arguments, both of them look like string contains numbers (1..20 or more). First - is the name of the folder, second - name of a file without extension. And i want when this method are called to load file "/res/raw/var1/var2", where var1 and var2 - arguments. Is there any way to do that? Thank you for answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you have, could you post what you tried?

Comment: Steps to undertake: 1. get the id from the R class 2. call Resources#openRawResource(int androidId)

Comment: @BradySheehan, i googled and tried something like that:

`void ShowText (int path, int name) {

        try {

            InputStream Text = new FileInputStream("res/raw/cities" + path + "/" + name);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }`
But not sure it's gonna work...

Sorry for noob questions and bad english.

Comment: @SuperPrower I think that might work. Have you tried it? sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getIdentifier as below

```
getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + var1 + "/" + var2, null, getPackageName())
```